# Integrating $\int_\gamma \frac{\cosh z}{2 \ln 2-z} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve the following integral using Cauchy Integral Formula:
$$\int_\gamma \frac{\cosh z}{2 \ln 2-z} dz$$

with $\gamma$ defined as:

1. $|z|=1$
2. $|z|=2$

With $|z|=2$ I've solved already, as it is quite easy. All one needs to do is re-write the denominator as $z-2 \ln 2$ and since $2 \ln 2$ is inside $\gamma$, then one can apply easily the formula.

With 1 I'm not sure how to re-write the integral so I can use the Cauchy Integral formula (Can I even do it?).

Comment: You can use the Cauchy integral theorem, since the integrand is analytic in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk.

Comment: @DanielFischer So it's 0.. How do you know that the integral is analytic in a neighbourhood of $\gamma$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part 1, we can use the fact that the integrand

$$\frac{\cosh z}{2\ln 2 - z}$$

is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{2\ln 2\}$, in particular, in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk, since $\cosh z$ is an entire function. Thus by the Cauchy integral theorem, the integral is $0$.

An alternative roundabout way is to consider the function

$$f(z) = \frac{z\cosh z}{2\ln 2 - z},$$

and note that the integral is

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z}\,dz = 2\pi i f(0).$$